# Autosize of TText not setting to 0 with emptystring

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe7

I set my TText to autosize and the text value to ""(empty string). But the width does not change to 0.

There is a [Fix](http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/30070) to a similar problem, but this does not help my problem.

The problem occurred when i updated my project from XE6 to XE7 and I have a style for my TGroupbox. In XE7 width and height have been replaced by size.width an size.height, where size is a TComponentsize object.

When the groupbox has no style, I don't want it to clip the border of the groupbox.

I added a `TFloatanimation` to the TText in the style, and set it to

```
property := "size.width"
**Duration := 0**
start :=0
stop  :=0
**enabled := true**
```

Now all my TGroupboxes run this animation to reset the width to 0. And if they have a text value, adjust fine. Is this the best solution, per formant? I have a max of 20 TGroupboxes on 1 form.

Comment: I'm afraid you are forced to manually setting the width of your TText to 0 because the AdjustSize method that is internally called on every text change is implemented so that it does nothing when the text is empty. Now I guess this might be implemented in such way so that clearing the text at design time while having AutoSize enabled would not make component 0 pixel wide and therefore not clickable in form designer. if my guess is correct then the EMB should have implemented this in such way that the component would not be resized only at design time but still resize at runtime. ...

Comment: I can't see the actual code right now, but a setter that checks if the new value is different from the old value usually does this to avoid doing a lot of stuff if there is no change anyway. Sometimes that makes sense, sometimes it doesn't. Doing this twice is probably a little over the top, though.

Comment: OK, just looked at the code for `TText.SetText`. I see nothing to complain about. It only checks *once*, not twice. Then, if there was a change, it adjusts the size and repaints. Looks fine to me. Assigning local variables is pretty fast. No big deal.